# Code runs much faster in C than in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote physics simulation code in python using numpy and than rewrote it to C++. in C++ it takes only 0.5 seconds while in python around 40s. Can someone please help my find what I did horribly wrong?

```
import numpy as np

def myFunc(i):
    uH = np.copy(u)
    for j in range(1, xmax-1):
        u[i][j] = a*uH[i][j-1]+(1-2*a)*uH[i][j]+a*uH[i][j+1]
    u[i][0] = u[i][0]/b
    for x in range(1, xmax):
        u[i][x] = (u[i][x]+a*u[i][x-1])/(b+a*c[x-1])
    for x in range(xmax-2,-1,-1):
        u[i][x]=u[i][x]-c[x]*u[i][x+1]
xmax = 101
tmax = 2000
#All other variables are defined here but I removed that for visibility
uH = np.zeros((xmax,xmax))
u = np.zeros((xmax,xmax))
c = np.full(xmax,-a)
uH[50][50] = 10000
for t in range(1, tmax):
    if t % 2 == 0:
        for i in range(0,xmax):
            myFunc(i)
    else:
        for i in range(0, xmax):
            myFunc(i)
```

In case someones wants to run it here is whole code: http://pastebin.com/20ZSpBqQ
EDIT: all variables are defined in the whole code which can be found on pastebin. Sorry for confusion, I thought removing all the clutter will make the code easier to understand

Comment: C/C++ is a compiled language that is known for its efficiency. Python/NumPy is an interpreted language known for its user-friendliness. Using one instead of the other is what you did wrong.

Comment: `for` loops will run basically in Python time, whether or not you have `numpy` arrays inside the loop.

Comment: You're writing NumPy like it's C. Explicit `for` loops are terrible for performance in NumPy.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for the answer. Can you please give me a hint how to write it properly and more efficiently?

Comment: And there are also plenty of references to global variables which doesn't help either.

Comment: @MaxK tell it to do operations on entire arrays. These are built in to numpy and implemented efficiently in C.

Comment: @Denziloe : Thank you for the advise editing only few lines increases performance drastically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when I ran your numpy python code it took four minutes to run, once I removed the numpy code and replaced it with standard python code it only took one minute! (I have a not so fast computer)

Here's that code:

```
#import numpy as np

def impl(i,row):
    if row:
        uH = u[:][:] # this copys the array 'u'
        for j in range(1, xmax-1):
            u[i][j] = a*uH[i][j-1]+(1-2*a)*uH[i][j]+a*uH[i][j+1]
        u[i][0] = u[i][0]/b
        for x in range(1, xmax):
            u[i][x] = (u[i][x]+a*u[i][x-1])/(b+a*c[x-1])
        for x in range(xmax-2,-1,-1):
            u[i][x]=u[i][x]-c[x]*u[i][x+1]
    else:
        uH = u[:][:] # this copys the array 'u'
        for j in range(1, xmax-1):
            u[j][i]= a*uH[j-1][i]+(1-2*a)*uH[j][i]+a*uH[j+1][i]
        u[0][i] = u[0][i]/b
        for y in range(1, xmax):
            u[y][i] = (u[y][i]+a*u[y-1][i])/(b+a*c[y-1])
        for y in range(xmax-2,-1,-1):
            u[y][i]=u[y][i]-c[y]*u[y+1][i]

#Init
xmax = 101
tmax = 2000
D = 0.5
l = 1
tSec = 0.1
uH = [[0.0]*xmax]*xmax #np.zeros((xmax,xmax))
u = [[0.0]*xmax]*xmax #np.zeros((xmax,xmax))
dx = l / xmax
dt = tSec / tmax
a = (D*dt)/(dx*dx);
b=1+2*a
print("dx=="+str(dx))
print("dt=="+str(dt))
print(" a=="+str(a))
#koeficient c v trojdiagonalnej matici
c = [-a]*xmax #np.full(xmax,-a)
c[0]=c[0]/b
for i in range(1, xmax):
    c[i]=c[i]/(b+a*c[i-1])
uH[50][50] = 10000
u = uH
for t in range(1, tmax):
    if t % 2 == 0:
        for i in range(0,xmax):
            impl(i,False)
    else:
        for i in range(0, xmax):
            impl(i,True)
```

I believe that this could be much faster if you were to have used numpy the correct way rather than as a substitute for arrays, however, not using numpy arrays cut the time to 1/4th of the original.

Comment: Also, there is no need for uH that I can see so if you wanted you could just remove that entirely.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I have to look into how to use arrays in NumPy efficiently if I want to use it efficiently.
EDIT: how can I remove uH if I calculate new values from old ones u[i]=u[i-1]+u[i+1]

Comment: You could store them in a single temporary variable as to not copy the entire array, should work not tested though

Comment: Replacing array by list improve performance, bun you will stay far from  C performance like that.  Numpy is the good approach, by you must learn it first ;).

Answer (score 2):

fundamentally, C is a compiled language, when Python is a interpreted one, speed against ease of use.

Numpy can fill the gap, but you must avoid for loop on items, which need often 
some skills.

For exemple,

```
def block1():
    for i in range(xmax):
     for j in range(1, xmax-1):
                u[i][j] = a*uH[i][j-1]+(1-2*a)*uH[i][j]+a*uH[i][j+1]
```

is in numpy style :

```
def block2():
     u[:,1:-1] += a*np.diff(u,2)
```

with is shorter and faster ( and easier to read and understand ?) :

```
In [37]: %timeit block1()
10 loops, best of 3: 25.8 ms per loop

In [38]: %timeit block2()
10000 loops, best of 3: 123 µs per loop
```

At last, you can speed numpy code with Just In Time compilation, what is allowed with Numba. Just change the beginning of your code like :

```
import numba
@numba.jit
def myFunc(u,i):
   ...
```

and the calls by  `myFunc(u,i)` at the end of the script (`u` must be a parameter for automatic determination of types) and you will reach the same performance (0,4 s on my PC).